# cakephp order by another model field in association

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, sql-order-by, model-associations

just one quick question about orderBy in cakePHP find operations. let's say I have 3 models associated with each other. When I do a `find('all')` cakePHP query on any of my 3 models, I get the results which also includes the data from the other 2 models. For example, let's say my models are:

```
1- User
2- School
3- Country
```

If I do `$this->find('all')` inside `UsersController`, because my three models are linked together I will get something like this:

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
         (
              [User] => Array
                     (
                          [id] => 'the_auto_incrementing_id'
                          // other table columns 
                          [created] 'creation_date'
                          [modified] 'modification_date'
                     )
              [School] => Array
                     (
                          [id] => 'the_auto_incrementing_id'
                          // other table columns 
                          [created] 'creation_date'
                          [modified] 'modification_date'
                     )
              [Country] => Array
                     (
                          [id] => 'the_auto_incrementing_id'
                          // other table columns 
                          [created] 'creation_date'
                          [modified] 'modification_date'
                     )
         )
)
```

My question is this, although my `find('all')` query was initiated on the `User` model, is it possible to `orderBy` let's say the `created` field in the model `School` for example?

Please let me know if that's possible at all

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get all the related data from User, School, and Country, but sort by `School.created` (per your example), you can just run the query from the School model.

I assume you're in the Users controller - if so, it'd just be this:

```
$myData = $this->User->School->find('all', array('order'=>'School.created DESC'));
```

(no need to load the school model, since it's linked, - so you an just refer to it through the User model)